# Trouble with javascript: drawing shapes at button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg, web

For the beginning of my assignment, I have a webpage where i have an input box that asks for a number, and a drop down menu with options to select a shape.

Below that is an SVG container that will draw that particular shape as many times as indicated in the text input, but the shape should only appear once because I have all iterations being drawn at the same location so they all overlap.

But anyways, my problem is that I have everything set up but when I give the input (a number in the text input and a shape in the drop down menu), its just not drawing the shapes.

When I choose option 1(circle) it does nothing

When I choose option 2(square) it does draw a square

When I choose option 3(triangle), it draws a super tiny triangle but the size I've specified in my code should make it at least as big as the square.

Here's my code. Where's my mistake?

HTML:

```
<main>

<h1>Assignment 4 : Zap-em</h1>

<p>Difficulty: <input type="text" id="howmany"/></p>
<p>
    Shape: 
    <select id="shape">
        <option value="a">Circle</option>
        <option value="b">Square</option>
        <option value="c">Triangle</option>
    </select>
</p>
<button id="btn">Start</button>

<div id="svg1"></div>

</main>
```

Javascript:

```
var typed, shape;

draw = function() {
    typed = $('#howmany').val()
    shape = $('#shape').val()


    for ( count = 0; count < typed; count = count + 1) {

        if (shape == "a") {
            circle = paper.cicle(100, 100, 25)
        }
        if (shape == "b") {
            square = paper.rect(100, 100, 50, 50)
        }
        else {
            triangle = paper.path('M25,0 L50,50, L0,50 Z')
        }
    }
}    



setup = function() {
  paper = Raphael('svg1', 400, 400)
    $('button').click(draw)
}
jQuery(document).ready(setup)
```

Comment: probably because the error is caused by a simple mistake which would have been caught by simply debugging yourself.

Comment: I've fixed that. Can you please give me an upvote to cancel the downvote?

Comment: Your're not allowed to change a question in such a way that it makes the answer invalid. If you continue to do that the moderators will step in and lock the question.

Answer (score 1):

There is a very simple error in your code. A spelling mistake. Spelling for `circle` is incorrect. Make that correct as below,

```
circle = paper.circle(100, 100, 25)
```

Then everything will be fine. You can find such an errors (specially js errors) with the `firebug` add-on in Firefox browser. It is exactly pointing out where the bug is.

Comment: I just fixed that but it still doesn't work. What else could have gone wrong?

Comment: @JohnnySack nothing, when I tried your code, and corrected `cicle` to `circle` it worked. Have you looked in the console for additional errors? Like missing jQuery or Raphael? Also, I've made a fiddle, the code looks a bit different, but this works: https://jsfiddle.net/2b4ys3je/

Comment: @JohnnySack check the libraries you have used as suggested by Alex. Because even my fiddle also working fine with that correction.

Comment: I'm using the jquery and raphael libraries provided by my school and it has worked for every other assignment i've done in the past. I wonder why it isn't working this time.